# Change CSS dynamically, some CSS rules do not work

Tags: javascript, css

The following js code allows me, with buttons, to dynamically change color to the body class, it works great.
However, in addition to `backgroundColor` I have tried to use other CSS rules, for example `color`, `borderColor`, on a button, and it works very well.

1) If I use `box-shadow` or `boxShadow` does not seem to work. Am I wrong or is there a list of CSS rules I can use?

2) `$('h2').css('backgroundColor', '#000');` to get a change of color on mouse over I tried `$('h2:hover').css('backgroundColor', '#ff0000');` but this does not work. Also in this case the reason is that dynamically you cannot use: hover? Or am I wrong?

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var nightMode = function() {

            $('body').css('backgroundColor', '#000');   

        },
        normalMode = function() {
            $('body').css('backgroundColor', '#fff');

        };

    $("#night-mode").click(function () {
        localStorage.setItem('modalread', 'night-mode');
        nightMode();
    });

    $("#normal-mode").click(function () {
        localStorage.setItem('modalread', 'normal-mode');
        normalMode();
    });

    if (localStorage.getItem('modalread') == 'normal-mode') {
        normalMode();   
    } else if (localStorage.getItem('modalread') == 'night-mode') {
        nightMode();
    }

});
```

Comment: `If I use box-shadow or boxShadow does not seem to work` what doesn't work? how do you try to use it?

Comment: `$('h2:hover')` - unfortunately that's not how jQuery works

Comment: do not confuse jquery selectors with css selectors. They look similar but they are not the same. for `hover` jquery has a method called `hover()` . CHeck it out.

Comment: see Documentation (https://api.jquery.com/hover/) about hover and change your code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can work with css classes that you define:

define a class:

```
.fancy-class:hover {
    color: yellow !important;
}
```

With switching the colors run:

```
$("h2").addClass("fancy-class");
```

This `$('h2:hover')` is not a valid class selector. Thats why your solutions doesnt work. To make your code easier to maintain I would in general recommend for this to work with css classes